# why Axios send two request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, request, axios

I need help with axios, I don't know why is sending two request [here an image of chrome network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7pNS.png) in one post call

I'm using react, and when I send request the function only trigger once (I debugged and put console.logs and get one response) but in chrome network I got two request, with different headers and type.
One have Authorization token, and the other don't have token[success request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyPFp.png)  and
[wrong request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82C7A.png) this is in one call and I don't know what is happening.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: 1. Would be better to include both requests information in the question instead of linking images; 2. What is the first request method? (I suspect OPTIONS and cors). Check out this article: https://codeburst.io/cors-story-of-requesting-twice-85219da7172d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it an [OPTION request?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS). `OPTION` requests are used to check if your client has permission to make the desired request to the API.

> The HTTP OPTIONS method requests permitted communication options for a given URL or server. A client can specify a URL with this method, or an asterisk (*) to refer to the entire server.

Comment: Oh! I did not know that, you are right, it's an option request, thanks!